# Update of jhipster generator won't work

Tags: hadoop-yarn, jhipster

*Jhipster* generator says that I should install the update:

> JHipster update available: 4.5.2 (current: 4.3.0)

If I try to run `yarn global upgrade generator-jhipster` as suggested, everything works fine.

```
success Saved 1 new dependency.
└─ generator-jhipster@4.5.2
warning No license field
✨  Done in 3.18s.
```

But if I try to generate a new project, I get the same update message again.
Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Do you have your Yarn package location in your PATH variable?  

`export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin"` https://jhipster.github.io/installation/

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to re-install generator-jhipster:

```
yarn global remove generator-jhipster
```

then

```
yarn global add generator-jhipster
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the exact same issue by :

- going  to `C:\Users\%yourLogin%\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin` and deleting these two files : `jhipster` and `jhipster.cmd`
- running : `yarn global add generator-jhipster`

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems could happen here. In general, handling NPM/yarn modules depend very on a proper installation of npm and yarn. In e.g. I often ran into different issues, as I installed yo and generator-jhipster using npm, while used them later in yarn. A clean install of npm, then yarn, then `yarn global add yo` and `yarn global add generator-jhipster` solved my issues.

The first thing I would check, is if you get the "update available" message in other directories, rather the project root. JHipster always places a copy of the currently used version to the project as you generate it the first time, to make sure you don't break your code when using newer JHipster versions for new projects, but still use `yo jhipster:entity` and other post-generation commands.

Another thing is if you use `jhipster` instead of `yo jhipster`. There is an issue that the JHipster client doesn't recognize a newer version, while `yo jhipster` does.

**if all that doesn't help**:
if the "nice" ways of solving your issue don't help, there is a "crowbar style" solution I can suggest:

- in a separate directory, run `git clone https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster`
- to specify the target version, check out a tag by `git checkout v4.5.2`
- run `yarn link`
- in your project root, run `yarn link generator-jhipster`

this will definitely will link the correct version into your project